# What is the term for a compulsive liar?

Tags: word-request

If a kleptomaniac is compulsive thief, which term is used for a compulsive liar?

I have searched extensively but to no avail. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: This could even go on EL&U

Comment: I'm partial to the phrase "serial fabulist," although it has the slightly more specific meaning of someone who continually makes up fake stories and passes them off as real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I could think of is mythomaniac. The definition of [**mythomania**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mythomania):

> An excessive or abnormal propensity for lying and exaggerating

Answer (score 0):

A term used is "[compulsive liar". Another term is "pathological liar".](https://www.aconsciousrethink.com/7043/pathological-compulsive-liars/)

Sometimes a distinction is drawn: pathological liars say whatever they think will benefit them most, they don't seem to know what is true and what is false. Compulsive liars know what is a lie, but they lie for no apparent benefit to themselves.

Typing "compulsive liar" into a search engine provides lots of further examples.